# PhantomJS Navigating Pages and complete fullwork flow

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have an application with the following structure.

`login.html >>> page1.html >>> page2.html`

You cannot get to page2.html without completing the previous pages. Now i know i am going about it the wrong way because i am stuck

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    system.stderr.writeLine('console: ' + msg);
};

function open_login(){
    login_page('https://test.com/login.html');
}

function login_page(file){
    page.open(file,function(){

        page.evaluate(function(){
        var user = document.querySelector('#username');
        var password = document.querySelector('#password');
        var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
        user.value = 'user1';
        password.value = 'pwd1';
        submit.click();
        });

        // What now? How do I ensure that the page1.html has loaded so that i can get more elements, their values and submit to proceed to page2.html

        page.render("login.png");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
           page.render("login.png");
           phantom.exit();
        }, 5000);
    });
}

open_login();
```

My problem now is that i have no idea what to do next, it will log in properly but how do i check with JavaScript that the `click` event has loaded the page1.html successfully? I cannot use jquery and i cannot user casperjs for this. Has to be phantomjs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback function [page.onLoadFinished](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html) that fires off every time when a page has finished loading. You can check for current url inside of that callback and do stuff accordingly.

```
page.onLoadFinished = function(result) {

    var current_url = page.evaluate(function(){
        return window.location.href;
    });

    if(result == "fail") {
        console.log("Couldn't load " + current_url);
        phantom.exit(1);
    }

    if(current_url.indexOf("page1.html") !== -1){
        do_stuff();
    }
    else if(current_url.indexOf("page2.html") !== -1){
        do_other_stuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out and see.

Comment: Well, how did it go?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, it didn't know that the page was loaded and still thought it was on the original page.

Comment: Did you implement checks from the answer? Or no longer necessary?

Comment: I did, i took a break from it because it was giving me a headache and i was going to go back to it later on.